Unable to search list on an MS Teams site - search does not work / does not seem to recognise the list in Teams
The Problem
I'm trying to search on the term 'cat flap', this is the title of an item in a Sharepoint list.  The list is located on the Teams site in question.

When viewed in Sharepoint the list has a list search box.
When viewed in Teams the list does not have a list search box.

Here is my list, it's very simple.  The list needs to be searchable, as it will act as a 'knowledge base':

MS Teams results page finds nothing, it does not appear to recognise the list on the site!:

Sharepoint Search works fine though...
When I open this MS-Teams site in Sharepoint Online, I can use the search to:

Search just the list
Search the entire site

Workarounds attempted

I created a page in Sharepoint and embedded the list onto it, with the idea that I could then use the list search functionality.  When I tried to add the link to a tab within the MS Teams site, it won't let me:


Why is search disabled in MS Teams??
Could it be that the search crawl needs to run?  The new list was only created an hour ago.  I note that Sharepoint ONline search finds stuff from the List, but Teams does not.
Additional Info
Apparently there used to be a List search box, but guess what, Microsoft removed it!  Well done Microsoft.

I can just confirm this behavior... And it seems like it's by design based on scopes Microsoft provide - Messages, People, Files, Group Chats. It seems like lists are just not in scope :-(
